# Access Database Alternatives

Tags: c#, .net, database

Ok before I explain... I know Access should basically not be used anymore.

My application now uses access for its portability.. its an internal application and makes private/internal database storage a snap.

Problem is, it uses JET 4.0 which is not supported in 64 bit operating systems and is frankly not very well implemented anymore.

I am developing using C# .NET visual studio 2008.  I am looking for a way to do this with some other database type that would not require me to install anything else on a users computer.  I looked into sqlite but there's no easy way to implement it in visual studio

An Ideas?

Comment: Access is still fine to use, as long as you know the limitations and don't try to get too clever with it

Comment: Take look at one of my question which is close to yours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990750/how-to-choose-light-version-of-database-system

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [SQL Server Compact 3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/compact.aspx) (the embedded version of SQL Server 2008).

Comment: That looks promising.  So I would not have to install any extra components on a users computer for this database to work?

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190958%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx you'll still need to install a runtime on the users pc

Comment: The runtime for sql server compact does not really *need* to install separat from your program, just reference the dll:s in your project and mark them as copy local and youll be ready to go.

Comment: There's a way to deploy it without have to install the extra stuff.  found it here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983326.aspx

Answer (score 4):

I recommend System.Data.Sqlite (http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/), a managed, open-source ADO.Net wrapper around the open-source Sqlite database. No installation required - you just include the single DLL in your solution. It boasts a small footprint, encryption, and good performance.

Comment: I use SQLite extensively for local data storage.  The great thing about it is no install.  Just make sure the System.Data.Sqlite library gets deployed with your app, and it works wonders.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server Express edition should come with Visual Studio.  It is an option at installation time, IIRC.

Answer (score 2):

Access has a couple of key characteristics:
 - Single-user
 - Requires installation

For alternatives this gives you (at least):

- SQL Compact (doesn't require installation, single-user)
- SQLite (doesn't require installation, single-user--although multi-user *is* supported)
- SQL Express (multi-user, requires install)

Comment: Access is not alawys single user, it's just a lot simpler that way.

Answer (score 2):

SQL CE is a good option as already mentioned.  You could also consider xml if the data is not private and you don't have concurrent users (which is very likely if you are using Access).  Xpath provides a lot of the features you would normally need from database queries and storage.  You also wouldn't need to install anything.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with H2?

The main features of H2 are:

> ```
> Very fast, open source, JDBC API  
> Embedded and server modes; in-memory databases  
> Browser based Console application  
> Small footprint: around 1 MB jar file size
> ```

Check out about implementation:

http://www.google.ba/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=C%23+h2+database

Answer (score 0):

This is one reason why people continue to use Access.  Of course you want an easy solution that doesn't require any installs on the client side.

We've all assumed so far your users are disconnected from your SQL Server.  If they can connect, you're home free.  It's less of a problem if you need to support read-only disconnected use, more of a problem if you need to pull updated data from disconnected users.

Can you tell us more about what you need?

Answer (score 0):

[Firebird](http://www.firebirdnews.org/docs/fb2min.html) can be a very good alternative to Access and have very good dot net driver

[Here](http://blog.cincura.net/231742-firebird-embedded-in-comparison-to-sql-server-compact-edition-4/) is a comparison between Firebird Embedded and SQL Server Compact Edition

Answer (score 0):

How about XML? Easy to use, and it works on any platform. Not the easies to implement if you're unfamiliar with it, but it's pretty rad once you learn how it works.