# Service based database vs SQL Server Compact vs LocalDB?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2013

My goal is to create a stand-alone C# Windows form application with 2-3 tables that will be installed on client machine with a installer file. And I don't want to install SQL Server 2008 software on client machine, I'm using Visual Studio 2013 C# for development.

My options are SQL Server Compct 4.0 but I don't see Visual Studio 2013 has inbuilt support for that, when I add  new item to project I don't see Compact (`.sdf`) file option there.

I've installed third-party SQL Server Compact Toolbox so I can create `.sdf` file and connectivity but I believe Microsoft is not giving support for compact db now.

I can see service-based database (`.mdf`) file which is actually a `LocalDb\\` something.

So what should I use if I don't want to install SQL Server 2008 on client but want to have db 
at client software?

Comment: If you have only 2-3 tables why don't you just use **MS Access** database ? Simply you can add the access DB as a file to installer project and can be easily deployed in client machines.

Comment: maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990750/how-to-choose-light-version-of-database-system

Comment: If you're using a `.mdf` file, or `LocalDB` - then you're using **SQL Server** (the full version) and thus you **MUST** install the SQL Server software on the client - possibly the Express edition or the further slimmed down LocalDB version - but still, you have to install something.

Comment: You want a SQL Database but you don't want to install any software? Perhaps you don't actually need a SQL database, perhaps you can use an XML file. As an aside, LocalDB is de facto at this point, and SQL CE is legacy software. Additionally, LocalDB offers a silent install mode, you can get the localdb.msi installers here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062

Answer (score 5):

You should mostly base your choice on your target platforms and the level of SQL Server functionality you expect.

**Target Platforms:**

LocalDB does not support older versions of Windows (e.g. Windows XP) or [WoW](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gauravseth/archive/2006/04/24/582091.aspx).  [Toad World's LocalDB overview](http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/b/weblog/archive/2014/01/02/what-is-localdb.aspx) has a good breakdown of its target-platform restrictions.

SQL Server Compact Edition has very few target-platform restrictions.  Check out its [download page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17876) under "System Requirements" for specifics.

**Functionality:**

LocalDB better approximates SQL Server Express functionally.  SQL Server Compact Edition has many functional limitations (e.g. no support for stored procedures).

[MSDN's introductory overview of LocalDB](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/07/12/introducing-localdb-a-better-sql-express.aspx) explains many of the important functional differences between LocalDB and SQL Server Compact Edition; and the aforementioned [Toad World LocalDB overview](http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/b/weblog/archive/2014/01/02/what-is-localdb.aspx) explains some of what (not) to expect from LocalDB functionally too.

**Redistribution:**

Both SQL Server Compact Edition (per the "Additional Information" section of its [download page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17876)) and LocalDB ([per SQL Server forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8116c668-1e07-47f1-8c12-275fcfcdcc50/redistribution-sql-server-2012-express-local-db?forum=sqlexpress)) are freely redistributable: so you should be okay with either with respect to fine print.

Comment: @marc_s: LocalDB is a _version_ of SQL Server Express - with restrictions and simplifications that do not apply to SQL Server Express proper. For example, SQL Server Express supports remote connections and protocols other than named pipes; LocalDB does not. The differences between LocalDB and full SQL Server Express may not matter in many situations, but differences do exist between them.  See the references I cited for numerous other examples.

Comment: Yes - but the fact remains - LocalDB is based on SQL Server Express and **requires** an installation - it cannot be used by just copying a few DLLs

Comment: @marc_s: Fair enough. The installer is smaller, and installing LocalDB is simpler.  Technically SQL Server Compact Edition [requires an installation too](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174619.aspx) - slipstreamed into app installation though it may be.  I see LocalDB as a shade of grey between full SQL Server Express and SQL Server Compact Edition in this respect.

Answer (score 2):

maybe SQLite would be an option? check out: http://www.sqlite.org/
it's just a DLL/Assembly you need to reference and it's pretty straightforward..